# stable of discrete-time system (transfer matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have [image: problem].

I don't know how to start it...

Would you give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1):

In time domain:
$$
y_n=CA^nx_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}CA^kB\underbrace{u_{n-1-k}}_{=\bar u}+D\underbrace{u_n}_{=\bar u}=\underbrace{CA^nx_0}_{\to 0}+\Bigl(\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}CA^kB+D}_{\to H(1)}\Bigr)\bar u\to H(1)\bar u.
$$
In frequency domain: the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=\lim_{z\to 1}(1-z^{-1})Y(z)=\lim_{z\to 1}(1-z^{-1})H(z)\frac{\bar u}{1-z^{-1}}=H(1)\bar u.
$$

Comment: Thank you~! I understand